# Internationaization with Spring3

Tags: spring, multilingual

I am kind of struck here and wondering if there is any way out of this with less overhead. The issue I am facing is I have a JSP page with userID/Password textfileds and language as a dropdown box with two languages "EN", "ES".

When I provide user/password and select "ES" from the drop down I do a POST to the @Controller method save the values to DB for that user. Then I am adding the changed language to the the model object as

```
model.addAttribute("language", request.getParameter("language"));
```

The return type of the method is STRING (name of the next JSP page).

The expectation is the next JSP page should show up in Spanish. But it does not happen. I have the "LocaleChangeResolver" defined in my myapp-servlet.xml as below:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>
```

In my JSP I have the tablib defined:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
```

The label I am trying to read from properties files is

```
<spring:message code="label.formName"/>
```

Can anyone help me here why the change of language is not being picked up by the JSP instead still shows the text in English instead of Spanish....

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to do if you want your program to "speak" in different languages.

For example I have the following configuration in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- Locale settings -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <!-- My file with messages are: messages_en.properties (for English) and messages_lt.properties (for Lithuanian) -->
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- I'm resolving my locale according to browser's Cookie -->
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="lt"/>
    </bean>
```

In my case I have two files: messages_lt.properties and messages_en.properties. In your case you need to create files called messages_en.properties (for English) and messages_es.properties (for Spanish). Each file should contain:

```
# messages_en.properties
label.formName=My form
```

and

```
# messages_es.properties
label.formName=Mi forma
```

Then (as you mentioned) you need to add taglib in your JSP page and use it:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<...>
<spring:message code="label.formName"/>
```

Hope this helps :)

EDIT: Nice tutorial at MKYONG.com: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Comment: Hi All thanks for the response, probably I was not so clear in asking the question. Anyway I was able to get this working the solution that I got is from the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418645/i18-message-property-does-not-reflect-in-jsp-through-controller

Comment: Nice to hear that :) Good luck! :)